# Django AbstractUser ManyToManyField did not get anything

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have created an abstract user model in Django. The user belongs to multiple services. When I register the user to database then the user has been register instead user_services. `user_services` are not stored in database while we register the new user.

models.py

```
class UserAbstract(AbstractUser):
    user_services = models.ManyToManyField(UserServices, related_name='services', blank=True)
    is_expert = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserAbstract
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
            'user_services',
            'is_expert',
        ]
```

views.py

```
def Register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            
            user = form.save()

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, f'{username} account has been registered!')
                return redirect('profile')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'user/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Can you add the `UserRegistrationForm`?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to add this line after save the user!

```
user = form.save()
user.user_services.set(services)  # services
```